# Silverlight pop-up Non-model Windows?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In Silverlight, how do I popup non-model windows? I want that user to interact with the parent window as well as child window at same time. What can I do?

Comment: You **don't have** to do your own! Tim Heuer has made one for us. Here is [blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/07/08/silverlight-floatablewindow-updated-with-resizing-capabilities.aspx) about it.

Comment: @Jumbo- I have tested it.But floatable window is not working like non-model window.Basically, I want to use radtreeview drag drop on child window. But according to me, in model window it never happens. Thats why I want to use non-model window.

Comment: I din't tested that control myself. On [codeplex project page](http://floatablewindow.codeplex.com/) is said that it can be used "for both modal and non-modal uses". According to [this blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/05/10/silverlight-childwindow-non-modal-refactor.aspx), there are two methods: `Show()` is for non-modal and `ShowDialog()` is for modal dialog. What exactly isn't working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement your own window...
Good way to do it is to have a canvas on top of your UI, after you will display window as child of that canvas and will be able to interact with your UI as well.